# Checking if a date in the past is a weekday

Tags: python, datetime

I'm finding this quite difficult and I'm not too sure which imports to use. Either way:

```
  from datetime import datetime
  from datetime import timedelta
  from datetime import date 
  import holidays 

  def isTradingDay(theDate):
    isWeekday = False
    isBankHoliday = False

    # Select country 
    holidayDates = holidays.UnitedKingdom() 

    #Check WeekDay and Bank Holiday status
    if(datetime.today().weekday() < 6):
      isWeekday = True

    if(theDate in holidayDates):
      isBankHoliday = True


    #Return True if trading day
    if(isWeekday == False and isBankHoliday == False):
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

The issue lies with `datetime.today().weekday() < 6` I want to use this line to check if the value `theDate` is a weekday. But I can't find the correct way of checking theDate.

theDate format is: `(datetime.today() - timedelta(days = offset)).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')`

Are there options that can be worked into the above?

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: What is the format of `theDate`? is it a string? `datetime` object?

Comment: Why do you check the day-type (0-5) vs `datetime.datetime.now()` and the `bankholiday` vs `theDate` ? shouldn't you use `theDate` both times (if it is a datetime-instance)?

Answer (score 0):

If `theDate` is the `datetime` object, you can use `.weekday()` function too:

`if(theDate.weekday() < 6):`

If it is a string, you should first convert it to datetime with [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

`dtime = datetime.strptime(theDate, '%Y-%m-%d')`

`'%Y-%m-%d'` string depends on your string format of `theDate`